# What should I do to make my app compatible with all the devices?

Tags: android, device

I made  an app and uploaded in play store. Problem is my app's Requires Android
10 and up. what should I do to make available for all device?

I have not done anything yet.
//I have

android {
compileSdkVersion 31

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: change `minimumSdkVersion` in gradle

Comment: Minimum SDK version depends on the kind of feature you are using like if you are using any feature which requires min sdk version to be android 10 then you won't be able to lower the version of min sdk.

Answer (score 2):

set compileSdk targetSdk minSdk

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct answer is to set minSdk